# Re-index pandas dataframe by union of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Probably a duplicate, but I'm not even sure what to search for.

If I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
index RH  LH  Data1  Data2 . . . 
1     A1  A2  A      B
2     B1  NaN C      D
3     NaN C2  E      F
```

And I want to re-index as so:

```
index Data1  Data2
A1    A      B
A2    A      B
B1    C      D
C2    E      F
```

Is there a simple-ish way to do this?  Or should I just do a pair of `for` loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with all columns without names defined in list and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then remove last level by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`, convert all another levels to columns and create index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['RH','LH']).tolist()
df = (df.set_index(cols)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(len(cols), drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='idx')
        .set_index('idx'))
print (df)
    Data1 Data2
idx            
A1      A     B
A2      A     B
B1      C     D
C2      E     F
```

Or use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), remove column `variable` and last create index by `idx` column:

```
df = (df.melt(cols, value_name='idx')
       .dropna(subset=['idx'])
       .drop('variable', axis=1)
       .set_index('idx'))
print (df)
    Data1 Data2
idx            
A1      A     B
B1      C     D
A2      A     B
C2      E     F
```